# Understanding pretty-printing with Formatter in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I have a formatter code like this:

```
let format ff x = Format.fprintf ff "%d" x
```

which is part of a larger module `ModuleName` with many other functions (let's call one of them `add`).

I know that `ff` argument is supposed to be where the output is going, say, `Format.std_formatter`.

However, after I do `#install_printer ModuleName.format;;` and then run something like `let sum = add 1 2`, I see that utop has formatted it properly. Yet I never passed in any argument to `ff`! Does OCaml simply default to `std_formatter`?

Comment: What do you mean by "I see that utop has formatted it properly"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OCaml REPL knows how to use printers registered with `#install_printer`, and it prints on std_formatter by default. However, this is a feature of the REPL, not of the language.